# Can a bound service start itself?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a service that is designed to run in the foreground and allow clients to bind to it. It is similar to a music foreground service (described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#bind-started-service)) that plays music and allows an app to bind to it and control actions like pause and play.

Specifically, I want the service to be in the foreground before it does any work as a result of a client binding to it.

I am aware of the `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag but that only *creates* the service; it does not put the service into the started state and also doesn't put it into the foreground.

<s>I am also aware that `bindService` returns a boolean indicating if the service is already created or not and that it can be used to start the service if it hasn't already, then bind to it.</s> (not true)

However, that allows for race conditions to creep in and also forces the client to keep track of service's state. I'd prefer for the service, in the `onBind` method, to start and put itself in the foreground. This leads me to the question.

Can a bound service start itself. Or in otherwords, can a service (named `MyService`) successfully call `startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));`?

Comment: Sure can, and you can call ``startForeground`` in ``onStartCommand``, but then you'll have to manage stopping it too

Comment: @cactustictacs Something that I didn't consider: can I put `startForeground` in the onCreate method. What would happen if a client bound the the service with the flag `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` and the service was **not** created beforehand? Would the service move to the foreground, even though it was never started?

Comment: You should probably read the whole section on Services, but here's the bit about foreground ones: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#start - you call ``startForeground`` *after* the Service has been *started*. *Binding* is a completely separate thing from *starting* - a *bound* service isn't necessarily *started*. Honestly it's probably a good idea to make a basic service app and play around with this stuff and work out what you can and can't do regarding your use-case

Comment: Quick update. After testing on an emulator, you can call `startForeground` inside of `onCreate` that was called as a result of `bindService(..., BIND_AUTO_CREATE)`. However, as expected, when the context that called `bindService` either unbinds or is destroyed then, the service is also destroyed.

Comment: That's not expected behaviour though - like I said binding is a separate thing, a service runs while it's *started* **or** *has something bound to it*. If you bind to it, start it, then unbind then it's still in the started state. But to keep running when your app (or anything else that binds to your service) is in the background, as well as *start*ing it you need to have called ``startForeground`` (like in the link I posted) and you need to meet the criteria imposed by the restrictions on foreground services

Comment: @cactustictacs I know that a bound service is not the same as a started service -- I did not mean to imply that they were. However, the guide that you linked to never actually stated that a foreground service *had to be* a started service. This, in combination with what I said in my last comment, creates a new question: Is it intended behavior for a bound only (i.e. not started) service to be able to become a foreground service.

Comment: It's the first line in the section I linked: *Before you request the system to run a service as a foreground service, start the service itself*. Bound services are for applications that are already in the foreground, so the service can stay as a background one. Once you leave that app (so it unbinds from the service) the service needs to be started so it keeps running, and it needs to be foregrounded so it isn't killed by the system

Comment: Here, this explains it more than I can in a comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification) *You must always call ``ContextWrapper.startService(android.content.Intent)`` first to tell the system it should keep the service running, and then use this method to tell it to keep it running harder.*