# Is it intended behavior for a bound-only service to become a foreground service?

Tags: android, android-service

This question is a result of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71983363/can-a-bound-service-start-itself).

Can a bound service call `startForeground`? The example code is below, but in brief, I was able to sucessfully call `startForeground` (i.e. the foreground notification appeared) inside of the `onBind` method even when the service was never started (i.e. no calls were made to `startService`). Is this intended behavior? I was under the (false?) notion that foreground services were only for started services.

This was tested on API level 32.

```java
public class MyService extends Service {

    // other implementation...
    // define myStartForeground which internally calls startForeground(...)

    private class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MyService getService() { return MyService.this; }
    }

    private final LocalBinder localBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        myStartForeground()
        return local_binder;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = // create ServiceConnection instance
    private boolean bound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this::onButtonClick);
    }
    
    private void onButtonClick(View view) {
        if(!bound) {
            bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } else {
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
        }

        bound = !bound;
    }
}
```